# How to consume dotnet web service with volley?

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-volley

There are simple connections to consume a php page, but lack information on how to consume a **DotNet** **webservice**. This WebService returns a string in json and the problem is how to make Volley to call the webservice **method**. If you try to call a webservice with volley it shows only the xml configuration page, but is not the result of the function. With SOAP we know we need to inform the url, namespace, method, if it's dotnet (dotnet = true) and everything. I.e., with SOAP we report the **method** to be called. But how to do this in Volley? Is it not possible to work with **volley** and **webservice** in **DotNet**?

Comment: Please ask in English or go to the right language portal.

Comment: included resume in english, thanks

Comment: could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are simple connections to consume a php page, but lack information on how to consume a DotNet webservice. This WebService returns a string in json and the problem is how to Volley call the webservice method. If you try to call a webservice with volley it shows only the xml configuration page, but is not the result of the function. With SOAP we know we need to inform the url, namespace, method, if it's dotnet (dotnet = true) and everything. I.e., with SOAP we report the method to be called. But how to do this in Volley? Is it not possible to work with volley and webservice in DotNet?

Comment: Mesma dúvida que tenho.